# Calling the compiler manually with correct options

Tags: cmake

For a `custom_command` creating precompiled headers, I'd like to call the compiler manually so that the output file stays in the input directory.

```
add_custom_command(OUTPUT foo.h.pch COMMAND ${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER} ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} foo.h)
```

This does invoke the compiler, but none of the options set via `add_definitions` and `include_directories` are passed. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to get this information from directory properties [COMPILE_DEFINITIONS](http://cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#prop_dir%3aCOMPILE_DEFINITIONS) and [INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES](http://cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#prop_dir%3aINCLUDE_DIRECTORIES).

See [get_directory_property()](http://cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#command%3aget_directory_property) command.